# How to change input date in `French` instead of `English`?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm setting an input date and i'm getting it in french in chrome but in English with Internet explorer ! i want it to be all in French!

I expect the output to be a calendar in French but i'm getting it in English when i use i.e ! in chrome it's in French as expected!

Comment: `<html lang="fr">` in your html tag.

Comment: Are you referring to the french input date format?

Answer (score 0):

Angular has built-in i18n (internationalization) that you can use to format date, numbers and provide multi-language description to your app.
https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Your specific problem, if I unterstood it well, is about showing dates in a specific format (like DD/MM/YY instead of MM/DD/YY). You can certainly do that with DatePipes and a bit of i18n config:

src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

// the second parameter 'fr' is optional
registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr');
```

From angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n):

> The DatePipe, CurrencyPipe, DecimalPipe and PercentPipe use locale
>   data to format data based on the LOCALE_ID.

So, just use the [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) as:

```html
<p>Today is {{today | date}}</p>
```

and you should see the trick.